# Typescript: render custom script tag throws error TS1005: '}' expected

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, typescript

I have a class `MyScriptTag.tsx` where I intend to render a call to a service's library included in the main layout. This is how it looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as Radium from 'radium';
import { getUser } from '../actions/user';


const MyScriptTag = () => {
  return (
    <script>
      window['ExtLibrary'] = window['ExtLibrary'] || { _queue: [], Push: function (o, p) {this._queue.push({ type: o, data: p }); } };
      ExtLibrary.Push('User', {
        eMail: getUser().email
      });
    </script>
  );
};

const Component = Radium(MyScriptTag);
export default Component;
```

And it's included in a `MainLayout.tsx` class the following way:

```
class MainLayout extends React.Component<any, any> {
  render() {
    const { isLoggedIn, isLoggingIn } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <section style={[styles.base]}>
          ...
          <MyScriptTag />
        </section>
      </div>
     )
   }
 }
```

Code is not compiling and this is the Error message I get:

```
error TS1005: '}' expected.
```

Might be a newby thing, since I haven't worked with typescript before. But I cannot find a way to fix it and googling didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You miss a `}` at the end of your `MainLayout.tsx`, to close the `class`.

Comment: sorry @Darkilen, i just edited the question to add it. The '}' is there in MainLayout. The issue is with MyScriptTag.tsx, because if I remove the script there it builds fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should wrap the code with `{}` inside JSX

```
<script>
      {
          window['ExtLibrary'] = window['ExtLibrary'] || { _queue: [], Push: function (o, 
  p) {this._queue.push({ type: o, data: p }); } };
          ExtLibrary.Push('User', {
            eMail: getUser().email
          });
      }
</script>
```